# Representing xml with text and attribute in JSON schema

Tags: javascript, json, xml, xsd

I am currently working on converting an xml and xsd formats to JSON schema and then drawing the tree structure in html as follows:

```
|root-
   |child1:string
   |child2:object
      |child21:number
   |child3:string
   |child4:object
      |child41:object
         |child411:string
      |child42:string
```

I assumed only the elements of type `object` and `array` to be parent elements and others to be leaf elements (parent and leaf nodes are manipulated differently). In the JSON schema `object` type element's children will be inside `properties` and `array` type element's children will be in `items`.

But I came across the following xml, an element with attribute, how to represent them in a JSON schema?

```
<shoesize country="france">abcd</shoesize>
```

If the `WHAT-TYPE` in the following is `string`, the tree-draw code will not recognize it as a parent and if it is `object`, the type is wrong. What is the correct and best way to represent it in a JSON schema?

```
shoesize:{
    type:WHAT-TYPE
    properties:{
        country:{
            type:"string"
        }
    }
}
```

Or should `properties` be changed to `attributes` and change the tree-draw code to detect `attributes` too?